# Side effects of changing blackboard bold font with \setmathfont

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math

I'm using Latin Modern Math as math font but, since I don't like the blackboard bold letters that come with it, I replace them with the ones from TeX Gyre Termes Math. I believe to achieve this, the following is correct

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=bb] % blackboard letters
```

Unfortunately the last line also introduces white space after `\big*` delimiters:

[image]

Compare with:

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=bb] % blackboard letters
\begin{document}

\[
\Bigl(\frac{d\symbf\varphi}{d\symbf\theta}\Bigr)^{\top} \frac{d\eta}{d\mu}
\quad \mathbb{R}^2
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: what if you put the `lmodern math` after `gyre`?

Comment: @naphaneal if reverse the order I get the same result as in the second picture

Comment: Strange... I can't predict what could be causing this. Unfortunately I probably can't investigate in the near future, apologies. Will attempt over the weekend. Can you file a bug on GitHub please?

Comment: with `\left(...\right)` it is ok

Comment: @WillRobertson I will

Comment: @WillRobertson: The problem is the implicit ` \right.` in the code. The \setmathfont with "range" changes the delcode of the period, it is then no longer in the operators font but in `__um_fam1` and one get a `Missing character: There is no ^^@ in font LatinModernMath-Regular` and some space. Everything works fine if I change in `\__um_setup_delcodes:` the delcode setting of the period  to `\__um_set_delcode:nnn {operators} {`\.} {\c_zero}`.

Comment: @WillRobertson: BTW: The problem is only with xelatex, but if I compile the example with lualatex I get a ` lualatex-math warning: "wrong-meaning"`. Not sure if this is a problem.

Comment: Worse: if I add `\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range=\int]`, this also changes back the blackboard bold font.

Comment: Thanks all -- I've been away from my computer and your investigation helps a lot! @egreg Yes, range processing is a big one on my todo list. Not sure if regression or always broken....

Answer (score 1):

With `\left(...\right)` instead and, of course,  an upright differential operator:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=bb] % blackboard letters
\begin{document}

    \[
    \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}\mbfitphi}{\mathrm{d}\mbfittheta}\right)^{\top} 
    \frac{\mathrm{d}\eta}{\mathrm{d}\mu}
    \quad \BbbR^2
    \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be gone with LuaTeX in TL 2016.  With XeTeX it is still broken, but Unicode math typesetting is in general broken in XeTeX.

Also `amssymb` and `amsfonts` are superfluous as `unicode-math` has all the symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}[range=\mathbb] % blackboard letters
\begin{document}

\[
\Bigl(\frac{d\symbf\varphi}{d\symbf\theta}\Bigr)^{\top} \frac{d\eta}{d\mu}
\quad \mathbb{R}^2
\]

\end{document}
```

With TeX Gyre Termes

[image]

Without TeX Gyre Termes

[image]