# Unexpected space when using `range` with `unicode-math`

Tags: unicode-math

When I use `range` in `setmathfont`, I'm seeing an unexpected space showing up in various cases. Here's my distilled MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, border = 0.2in]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter {\set} {\{} {\}}

\begin{document}
\centering\large

\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
% Correct
\begin{tabular}{>$c<$}
  \set{2, 3} \\
  \set[\big]{2, 3}
\end{tabular}

\smallskip
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont[range={cal}]{Latin Modern Math}
% Incorrect -- extra space on the second line after the brace.
\begin{tabular}{>$c<$}
  \set{2, 3} \\
  \set[\big]{2, 3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The result is below — note the extra space after the brace in the 4th line. 
[image]

The only difference is the addition of `\setmathfont[range={cal}]{Latin Modern Math}`. Unless I'm misunderstanding, that should have no effect in this case since we're not displaying anything using `\mathcal`.

BTW, unlike other similar questions, I'm not using LuaTeX.

Comment: You probably also have a “Missing character” warning in your log

Comment: Imho it is the same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302628/side-effects-of-changing-blackboard-bold-font-with-setmathfont

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes. The example hangs for me with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: See https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/351

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, this seems to be the same bug. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the pointer to bug. Interestingly, no "Missing character" warnings that I see.

Comment: @Derek `Missing character: There is no ^^@ ...` in the log file (not on the terminal); there *must* be twice. You see the warning also on the terminal if you add `\tracinglostchars=2` at the top of the file.

Comment: @egreg You are correct! I was just looking at the terminal output. The messages are in the log file.